# Security Policy Error Calling Java Web Service From .Net

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, c#-4.0

I am trying to call a Java web service, over Http not Https, using .Net. The only hint I got from the web service team is to pass the credential either in SOAP message or in the endpoint settings.

I have created a simple console application and added a service reference to the web service. The following is the generated binding (I see that there is warning about unrecognized policy but cannot figure what it means or whether it is relevant or not):

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="CurrencyInformationServiceSoapBinding">
        <!--    WsdlImporter encountered unrecognized policy assertions in ServiceDescription 'http://www.openuri.org/':    -->
        <!--    <wsdl:binding name='CurrencyInformationServiceSoapBinding'>    -->
        <!--        <ns1:SupportingTokens xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200512">..</ns1:SupportingTokens>    -->
        <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
            messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </textMessageEncoding>
      <!--<security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" allowInsecureTransport="true"/>-->  
      <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
            realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Here are my trials:

**Trail #1:

-----------**
Using the following code:

```
CurrencyInformationServiceClient client = new CurrencyInformationServiceClient();  
foreignCurrencyDTO[] results = client.getAllForeignCurrencies();
```

or supplying the credentials in Windows property

```
CurrencyInformationServiceClient client = new CurrencyInformationServiceClient();  
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("crmuser", "welcome1");  
foreignCurrencyDTO[] results = client.getAllForeignCurrencies();
```

or supplying the credentials in UserName property

```
CurrencyInformationServiceClient client = new CurrencyInformationServiceClient();  
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "someuser";  
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "somepassword";  
foreignCurrencyDTO[] results = client.getAllForeignCurrencies();
```

resulted in

```
 System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Error on verifying message against security policy Error code:1000
```

**Trail #2:

-----------**
As per one comment I have seen, I have tried to add the following tag in the binding and call the web service by passing the credentials in UserName property of ClientCredentials

```
<security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" allowInsecureTransport="true"/>
```

but the result was

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties. This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security.
```

**Trail #3:

-----------**
I have tried to use WSHttpBinding instead of the CustomBinding generated by VS as follows:

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("http://someurl/CurrencyInformationService.jws");
CurrencyInformationServiceClient client = new CurrencyInformationServiceClient(binding, ea);
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "someuser";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "somepassword";
foreignCurrencyDTO[] results = client.getAllForeignCurrencies();
```

but the result was

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://someurl/CurrencyInformationService.jws.  The client andservice bindings may be mismatched. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.
```

**Update:

-----------**
I have received a working request from the vendor and tried it in soapUI and it gave a correct response.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soap:Header>
                <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
                        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="SecurityToken-35598fb7-5aa2-4623-b07b-3277c6578beb" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                                <wsse:Username>someuser</wsse:Username>
                                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">somepassword</wsse:Password>
                        </wsse:UsernameToken>
                </wsse:Security>
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
                <getAllForeignCurrencies xmlns="http://www.openuri.org/">
                </getAllForeignCurrencies>
        </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can someone give me a hint how to generate such a SOAP request?

Comment: you need to ask from the service vendor a working SOAP message sample. Then you can configure WCF to support it.

Comment: @YaronNaveh I have added a working SOAP request. Can you guide me to configure the application to generate the same request from .Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use SSL use this:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="NewBinding0">
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
                </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

If no SSL then use [CUB](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html).

Comment: Hi Yaron, I used CUB and I can see the correct request and response in fiddler. I have also used the request captured by fiddler and tried it in soapUI and I got the correct response. However in the .Net application I got "Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message ...". Any idea on how to ignore that.

Comment: It seems the solution is to add <security enableUnsecuredResponse="true" /> in the client config but I get the exception "Unrecognized element 'security'." Any suggestion?

Comment: does it accepts the security element w/o allowInsecureTransport? use .net 4.5

Comment: Same issue with .Net 4.5. If I add <security allowInsecureTransport="True" enableUnsecuredResponse="True"/> or just <security enableUnsecuredResponse="True"/> in the myClearUsernameBinding I get the same error "Unrecognized element 'security'."

Comment: CUB does not support it OOTB, but you can add it in code here https://github.com/yaronn/ClearUsernameBinding/blob/96a742ad02be19754d1f08323d199bf6fdce4e9b/ClearUserPassBinding/ClearUsernameBinding.cs ust create the SecurityBindingElement in some variable and set allowInsecureTransport on it. However I don't think this setting is relevant for you - seems like the server returns some error so this will not help you. You need to turn on WCF trace or check your inner exception

Comment: Thanks Yaron, I have changed the code to var clientSbe = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
clientSbe.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
res.Add(clientSbe);

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue while consuming a java web service using .Net, and this thread helped me partially in being able to consume web service.

But, somehow I came across this post and it worked as a final solution for me : http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/24/WCF-WSSecurity-and-WSE-Nonce-Authentication

Below settings worked fine for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="CustomSoapBinding">
          <security includeTimestamp="false"
                    authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
                    defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic256"
                    requireDerivedKeys="false"
                    messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11"></textMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://notrealurl.com:443/services/RealTimeOnline"
                binding="customBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="CustomSoapBinding"
                contract="RealTimeOnline.RealTimeOnline"
                name="RealTimeOnline" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"
                      sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```